# Local images from the app directory are not loading in Android Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm working on already developed Ionic based Mobile Application. While running the App on IOS, everything goes fine. But while running the app on android device, The images are not shown. and in the console it gives error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   file:///android_asset/www/assets/images/settings/new-device.png

```
<img ng-src="assets/images/settings/new-device.png">
```

Help me out of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, there is no file found in the file path you have provided. So change ng-src="assets/images/settings/new-device.png" to ng-src="images/settings/new-device.png" or ng-src=settings/new-device.png" and check..

Comment: actually I've already tried that too. "assets" is folder in which I've my CSS and Images... So I'm confused that why it is working fine in IOS but not in Android...